# Access violation error using DOM Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, dom

I'm building a software to process orders on a site. I'm using DOM to navigate through the website and I want my app not to hang when I use a command on the "wrong" page.

Ex:

```
try
  WebBrowser.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('ContentPlaceHolder1_txtCommande').setAttribute('value', lblDate.Caption);
except
end;
```

All I want is for the error to be ignored if the field is not found as this error is not important. Thank you!

Edit: wrote ADO when I meant DOM

Comment: Your question title and description do not match. ADO is for database access, and WebBrowser is wrapper for IE browser control object (COM). It has nothing to do with ADO. Another thing, you should not directly access the GetElementID like that, instead get the document, cast it to IHttpElement/IHttpElement2 and check for nil, or you can check it with if Supports(...,...,...) function.

Comment: Note that the document and element(s) may or may not be available (you may want to utilise onDocumentComplete and onNavigationComplete events). Also DocumentComplete event may be fired several times during loading a site. This is normal, and you have to deal with it as well.

Comment: Actually, I'm looking for an easy way to do this as I don't want to change all my code. onDocumentComplete and onNavigationComplete won't help me here since I have no way to verifyI'm on the right page without parsing the source of the page.

Comment: What I meant is the 'body' element for example, or other element on the page might not be available while the document is still loading, so you may or may not get the 'AV' error, and hence not reliable. If you put the code after the document finished loading, then the element is available (if it is there at the first place). Your code might be working (no AV) thrown, but during slow internet access time, it might break.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You yourself say that the element might not be found, so what do you expect

```
WebBrowser.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('ContentPlaceHolder1_txtCommande')
```

to return other than `nil` in that case? Yet you "blatantly" use whatever is returned by appending

```
.setAttribute('value', lblDate.Caption);
```

to it.

Change your code to

```
var
  element: IDomElement; // Whatever it should really be
begin
  element := WebBrowser.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('ContentPlaceHolder1_txtCommande');
  if Assigned(element) then
    element.setAttribute('value', lblDate.Caption);
```

**Edit**

if you are working with variants instead of using msxml through its type library or some other xml library in which you can find the proper type returned by GetElementID, then, as @GerryColl mentions, you can use `element: OLEVariant` and check for NULL instead of for a nil pointer.

Comment: // Whatever it should really be. What do you mean by that?

Comment: I've searched all over and I'm sorry but I don't understand what type of variable "element" should be...

Comment: @Gab: the actual type returned by GetElementByID (didn't have Delphi open)

Comment: @Gab: use code completion/code insight/code .... When you hover over GetElementID you should get some information about it. Another way would be to Ctrl-Click on GetElementByID and check the code where it is declared.

Comment: It won't show anything when I hover/ctrl-click. Also noticed that the code does not auto completes. Maybe I don't have the right "uses"?

Comment: @Gab: you don't see anything because you are working with Variants. CodeInsight does not work on Variants that wrap com objects.

Comment: Element can be declared as OLEVariant `var element: OLEVariant;`. If the element doesn't exist it will be equal to Null (Variant, not nil pointer).

Comment: @GerryColl: thanks, added that. My answer was based on working with msxml or the sax parser for which you can find the proper declarations in the (type) library.

Comment: @GerryColl: I still get a compiling error at this line `if Assigned(element) then` of incompatible type.

Comment: Ok found out, since "element" is not a pointer, you have to use the function VarIsNull in the If statement. But that seems to always return FALSE...

Comment: @MarjanVenema: The function we were looking for in this case is VarIsClear. Replaced it in my code and it worked like a charm. Thanks to you both!